# How to access a realm database from multiple controllers - swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am attempting to make a to-do app with a controller for both "this week" and "next week." (Objects with a date in the current week will be shown in the `thisWeek` view controller, while objects with a date next week will be shown in the `nextWeek` view controller. However, sometimes objects will not appear in the table until the app restarts, and I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.

In the `thisWeek` class (which is also my initial view controller), I initialize my database like so:

```swift
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
      schemaVersion: 1,
      migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: ToDoListItem.className()) { (_, newItem) in
                newItem?["notes"] = ""
                newItem?["isReoccuring"] = false
            }
        }
      })

    lazy var realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

This worked fine and there weren't any issues. However, I don't know how best to access this db from another controller (`nextWeek`). This was my first attempt: (which is what I also use in the object entry controller, where objects are first added to the db)

```swift
    lazy var realm = try! Realm()
```

I also added a `refresh()` to each controller's `viewDidLoad()` with the intention of refreshing the table every time the view is loaded. But it didn't help every situation.

```swift
    func refresh(){
        data = sortContent(arg: realm.objects(ToDoListItem.self).map({ $0 }))
        thisTable.reloadData()
    }
```

The issue with this is that some objects do not appear in their proper place until I restart the app. Only then do all objects appear properly. For example:

- something created in the `nextWeek` controller with a date in the current week will not appear until app restarts
- when an object in created in `nextWeek` controller, then date is changed from next week to this week, again, needs an app restart

Things that do work include:

- something created in the `thisWeek` controller with a date in the next week will appear immediately
- when an object is created in `thisWeek` controller, then date is changed from this week to next week works immediately

I thought I needed a way to sync the different "instances" of the db, but there may be another issue that I just don't know about. Any insight would be helpful

Would be happy to share more code snippets if more information is needed.

**UPDATE**

This is in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        let config = Realm.Configuration(
          schemaVersion: 1,
          migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: ToDoListItem.className()) { (_, newItem) in
                    newItem?["notes"] = ""
                    newItem?["isReoccuring"] = false
                }
            }
          })
        
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
        let realm = try! Realm()
        return true
    }
```

And everywhere I need to use realm (`thisWeek` and `nextWeek` controllers, etc), I use:

`let realm = RealmService.shared.realm`

Again, only certain functionalities are properly working

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's very important that questions are asked in a way that conforms to the format for the site. Please include images and code in the question, not links, and no Images code. Links can break and if that happens, it invalidates the question. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please update your question and we'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, much more clear and hopefully my answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

First the code in the section *I initialize my database* initializes that database var with a config.

```
lazy var realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

The next section could be a 'different' realm as no config is specified

```
lazy var realm = try! Realm()
```

Please review [Local Migrations](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#local-migrations), noting that a migration should occur when the app is first launched, not every time realm is accessed

> Inside your application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

In other words, perform the migration on app launch (ensuring to include `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config`) and then after that use

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

to access a local realm.

You will probably not want to do this:

```
data = sortContent(arg: realm.objects(ToDoListItem.self).map({ $0 }))
```

Realm objects are live updating and that code casts the realm objects to an array which not only 'breaks' the link between the objects and their backing data, it also loads ALL of the objects into memory, defeating their lazily loading nature. This can overwhelm a device and cause a crash. See [Realm Key Concepts](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/objects#key-concepts) and [Read Characteristics](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/reads#read-characteristics)

To answer the question;

> I thought I needed a way to sync the different "instances" of the db

You don't. You should access a realm the same way every time. Objects created on different realms are tied to that realm and trying to access them from a different realm will cause a crash.

One solution is to use a Singleton pattern, sometimes called a RealmManager or RealmService (search here on SO for those key words). While there is some debate about singletons in Swift, it works for this case.

Another solution is to have a master controller which 'talks' to realm and then sub viewControllers get their connection to realm from the master viewController. The would be a simple matter of instantiating the sub viewController from the master viewController and passing and/or assigning a property in the sub viewController. So conceptually something like this.

```
MasterVC
   func getRealm() -> Realm {
       //return a realm instance
   }
   
   func createSubVC {
      let mySubVC = SubViewController()
      mySubVC.realm = gGetRealm()
   }
```

But for simplicity and maintenance, I would suggest a singleton pattern for this use case. You could do something like this; create a file and put this code in it

```
import RealmSwift

func gGetRealm() -> Realm? {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        
        return realm
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error!")
        print("  " + error.localizedDescription)
        let err = error.code
        print(err)
        let t = type(of: err)
        print(t)
        return nil
    }
}
```

then whenever you need a realm instance in your app

```
func saveData() {
    if let realm = gGetRealm() {
       try! realm.write {
           //save some data
    }
}
```

or a RealmService singleton

```
import RealmSwift

class RealmService {
    private init() {}
    
    static let shared = RealmService()

    lazy var realm: Realm = {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        
        return realm
    }()
}
```

accessed like this

```
let realm = RealmService.shared.realm
```

Comment: I may need your help again. I created the `RealmService` class in its own file (with my specific config in there as well) and then used `RealmService.shared.realm` every other time I needed to do something with the db, but I still had the same issue. Am I missing a step?

Comment: @wanders Hard for me to know if you're missing a step but as long as whenever you need realm you call the RealmService, it will work. I don't know what you're specific config is but if it's a migration, it should only be called in appDelegate once. Perhaps you can update your question with your RealmService code and how you call it from within your controllers.

Comment: please see UPDATE section for the code I've been using

Comment: @wanders Ah yes, you are missing one step. Right after this `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config` you need to immediately call `let realm = try! Realm()` which will actually fire the migration at that time. If you don't call it, the migration will fire later and get weird.

Comment: Nope, still didn't work. Makes me wonder if the issue isn't with realm at all, but rather the relationship between the different controllers. Both the `thisWeek` and `nextWeek` controllers have a right bar button item that leads to `entryViewController` where new items are created. When this view is shown, it too is embedded in the tab bar controller, even though there isn't a relationship between them according to storyboard.  Is there a way to isolate it so realm can't tell what controller the item is coming from? Thoughts?

Comment: @wanders Once you've created a singleton for Ream, it can be accessed anywhere and from any controller regardless of their structure; that's the point of a Singleton like RealmService. Take a look at this [article](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift/) that's high level but explains Singleton if you are not familiar. I think the point here is that your code is failing because of something other than what was asked in your question... *how to access realm from multiple controllers* as my question answers that. We need to look elsewhere in your code.